# Appium Java test automation throws org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. How to fix?

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, mobile, appium

I am performing automation on one of the EdTech app, with the following code, where the app gets launched in Android studio Emulator and basic functionalities are checked. I have written the below basic code which will open an application and click on particular element:

```
`<sup><kbd>package outskill.appium;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumBy;
//import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

import io.appium.java_client.android.options.UiAutomator2Options;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
//import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
//import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

//import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
//import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
//import java.time.Duration;

public class outskillbasics {

    @Test
    public void outskilltest() throws MalformedURLException {
        //start appium server
        AppiumDriverLocalService service = new AppiumServiceBuilder().withAppiumJS(new File("C:\\Users\\Kirti Singh\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\lib\\main.js"))
                .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1").usingPort(4723).build();
        service.start();
        
        UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options();
        options.setDeviceName("Kirti Emulator");
        options.setApp("C://Users//Kirti Singh//eclipse-workspace//appium//src//test//java//outskillapp//app (2).apk");
        AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), options);
        driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.Button\r\n"
            )).click();
       driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.Button\r\n"
            )).click();
       boolean isPresent =  driver.findElement(AppiumBy.accessibilityId("Increase your knowledge in domains like Self-Help, Business, Art, & beyond with Audiobook Summaries, handpicked by the best mentors.")).isDisplayed();
       System.out.println(isPresent);
       driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.Button\r\n"
            )).click();</kbd></sup>`
```

While executing an Appium script the app is getting open and getting quickly closed with below error message:

```
error : org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: socket hang up 
Host info: host: 'LAPTOP-0OBQI7FL', ip: '192.168.1.3'
Build info: version: '4.9.1', revision: 'eb2032df7f'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.6'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[{appium:deviceName=Kirti Emulator, platformName=ANDROID, appium:automationName=UIAutomator2, appium:app=C://Users//Kirti Singh//eclipse-workspace//appium//src//test//java//outskillapp//app (2).apk}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {appium:app: C://Users//Kirti Singh//ecl..., appium:automationName: UIAutomator2, appium:deviceName: Kirti Emulator, platformName: ANDROID}}]
Capabilities {appium:app: C://Users//Kirti Singh//ecl..., appium:automationName: UIAutomator2, appium:deviceName: Kirti Emulator, platformName: ANDROID}
```

Mainly the session is not getting created after executing a script.